# Our Server HP ProLiant DL380 Gen 8 Hard Drive Not Detecting

Tags: windows-server-2016, hp, application-server

Our Server is working fine since long time, today once our server has restarted suddenly we found the boot error. After short time we identified our Raid drives are not deducted by the Server.

Following error i found while starting :

1792 Slot 0: Drive array  - Valid Data Found In Write Block Cache.
Data will automatically be written on drive array.
The following disk drive(s) are failed and should be replaced:
Part 1l: Box 2: Bay3

1716: Slot 0 Drive Array - Unrecoverable Media Error Detected on Drives during previous Rebuild or background surface analysis (ARM) scan. Error will be fixed automatically when the sector(s) are overwritten, backup and restore recommended.

Can any one help me how can i sort out this issue

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, one of your drives has died and needs to be replaced.

The second message (1716) indicates that a read error has been detected (likely an additional one) that would prevent full recovery. You might need to restore the lost data from backup.

For the future, make sure that you configure data scrubbing/media patrol to test all data on a regular basis before anything is lost permanently. You should also consider using a RAID level that provides multiple redundancies (RAID 6 or 60).

Comment: Thanks for your reply 
Sorry for asking the the lame question? 
"You might need to restore the lost data from backup." Do you mean the data from the windows backup? or RAID backup (I don't know either we have RAID backup or not? 

Another question: If i replace the HD do i required reconfiguration or it's automatically deducted.

Comment: From your server backup, whatever you're using. What kind of RAID controller are you using? Most support hot-plug but not all. On a hot-plug controller you should just pull the dead drive and plug a replacement (consult the manual, just in case). Without hot-plug it might be more complicated, check the manual. Drive replacement should always be well documented in your organization as any mistake might have a huge impact.

Comment: humm, I have an expertise in Software development not in this area so i need to find someone who do it for me because that was managed by 8 or 9 year back with another company which is no more exists.

Comment: Please don't take it personally but running a server for many years without any expertise in the organization is... brave.

Comment: what i mean is we have another team member who have this expertise  but he is on vacation now a days so i am handling it temp